# Same code, Bluetooth Module working fine on Android 11, but missing devices in Android 11+

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-manifest, flutter-androidmanifest

I'm using flutter_reactive_ble and flutter_blue_plus
in case of both libraries, when the code is built on android 11, the bluetooth module works quite fine. Incase of Andorid 11+ it doesn't show some of the scanned devices.

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- permissions handling -->

<!-- Bluetooth -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />



<!-- Notifications -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


<!-- Camera -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<!-- Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:label="melo"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

scanning code(working fine over android 11, and missing some devices android 11 onwards):

```
import 'package:animated_custom_dropdown/custom_dropdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'package:melo/ble/ble_scanner.dart';
import 'package:melo/providers/new_instrument_provider.dart';
import 'package:melo/screens/instrument_enrollment/primary_info.dart';
import 'package:melo/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:melo/widgets/add_instrument/bluetooth_scan_item.dart';
import 'package:melo/widgets/add_instrument/steps.dart';
import 'package:melo/widgets/others/theme_button.dart';

class SelectInstrumentScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const SelectInstrumentScreen({super.key, required this.collectionName});
  final String collectionName;

  @override
  ConsumerState<SelectInstrumentScreen> createState() =>
      _SelectInstrumentScreenState();
}

class _SelectInstrumentScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<SelectInstrumentScreen> {
  final BleScanner bleScanner = BleScanner(
    ble: FlutterReactiveBle(),
    logMessage: (message) {},
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bleScanner.startScan([]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.watch(newInstrumentProvider);
    bool areValuesSelected = ref.read(newInstrumentProvider)['type'] != null &&
        ref.read(newInstrumentProvider)['macAddress'] != null;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leadingWidth: 0,
        foregroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        title: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: const StepsIndicator(step: 1),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                const Text(
                  'Select Sensor Device',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Select the sensor device that you want to connect from the available devices.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: secondaryColor,
                    fontSize: 13,
                  ),
                ),

                // select instrument from a list of options
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const Text(
                  'Choose Instrument',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                CustomDropdown<String>(
                  closedHeaderPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 7, bottom: 8, left: 15, right: 10),
                  decoration: CustomDropdownDecoration(
                    closedBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                    closedBorder: Border.all(
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220, 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                  overlayHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                  hintText: 'Choose Instrument',
                  items: _listInstruments,
                  initialItem: ref.read(newInstrumentProvider)['type'],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    ref
                        .read(newInstrumentProvider.notifier)
                        .update('type', value);
                  },
                ),

                // bluetooth scanned devices
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const Text(
                  'Available Bluetooth Devices',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                // reactive ble devices
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<BleScannerState>(
              stream: bleScanner.state,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final discoveredDevices = snapshot.data!.discoveredDevices;
                  // sorting: nearest device first
                  discoveredDevices.sort((a, b) => b.rssi.compareTo(a.rssi));
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: discoveredDevices.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final device = discoveredDevices[index];
                      return Material(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            ref
                                .read(newInstrumentProvider.notifier)
                                .update('macAddress', device.id);
                            ref.read(newInstrumentProvider.notifier).update(
                                'name',
                                device.name.isNotEmpty
                                    ? device.name
                                    : 'Unknown Name');
                          },
                          child: BluetoothScanItem(device: device),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Text('nothing so far');
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 60,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: ThemeButton(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    name: 'Back',
                    isSimple: true,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: ThemeButton(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (areValuesSelected) {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return PrimaryInfoScreen(
                              collectionName: widget.collectionName);
                        }));
                      }
                    },
                    name: 'Next',
                    isDisabled: !areValuesSelected,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

const List<String> _listInstruments = [
  'Acoustic',
  'Bass',
  'Bowed',
  'Brass',
  'Drum',
  'Electric',
  'Mandolin',
  'Piano',
  'Reed',
  'Other',
];
```

Comment: What is "Andorid 11+"? Did you follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions)?

Comment: by android 11+ I mean android 12, android 13, android 14....

Comment: yup I've followed the documentation

Comment: If you had followed the documentation, I would expect your software to work. ;-) Can you show your issue as an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: check now please

Answer (score 1):

Since the release of Android 12, new Bluetooth permissions have been introduced. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions), BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, and BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE are considered runtime permissions.

This means that if your application is targeting devices running Android 12 or higher, you must handle these permissions yourself and request them explicitly from the user.

For example, when you intend to scan for BLE devices, you must request the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission. Note that this permission will be presented to the user as "Nearby devices" permission.

Failure to request and obtain these permissions may result in your BleScanner being unable to detect any nearby devices.

Note that for devices lower than Android 12, you still need to ask for runtime location permission.

Comment: hey thanks, but the main issue was, I'm using two flutter libraries for bluetooth in same application. and that was the reason it was missing out some of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of using flutter_reactive_ble and flutter_blue_plus at the same time in same application. Removing flutter_reactive_ble worked for me.